# Jmeter--How to write testdata succesful url without All Gone urls

Tags: jmeter

i want to write successful urls to a file to create testdata for a travel website.But some of the urls are giving all gone(no dates,fights available).How can i write only the succesful url without all gone urls in the file in jmeter?

Comment: You are asking for a tutorial. Instead, try to come up with your own solution, and if it doesn't work, post more specific questions here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly you are writing the URLs, here is a couple of the most common approaches:

1. Using JMeter [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)

   - Add If Controller to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
   - Use `JMeterThread.last_sample_ok` as the condition. **JMeterThread.last_sample_ok** is a [pre-defined variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) holding the previous sampler execution result (`true` if it is successful and `false` otherwise) so If Controller children will be executed only if the previous sampler is successful.
   - Put sampler(s) which write URLs into the file under the If Controller (as child(ren)
2. Using [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and the following code:

   ```
   if (prev.isSuccessful()) {
       def fileWithUrls = new File('fileWithUrls.txt')
       fileWithUrls << prev.getUrlAsString()
       fileWithUrls << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   }
   ```

   `prev` is a shorthand to [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance holding the previous sampler result data so the URL will be appended to the file only if the request was successful.